# extract one column from a var using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

i have something like this

```
var emp = db.Employees.toList();
```

in my employees table i have emp name, emp id and salary, using linq with lambda expressions, how do i access emp id in some another variable.
I have tried looking up for it, couldn't find a solution which does it using linq with lambda expressions

```
var employeeLeaves = db.Leaves
     .Include("Employee")
     .Include("Employee.Manager")
     .Where(l => l.Status.Id == 1)
     .GroupBy(l => l.Employee.Manager.Id)
     .Select(l => l.GroupBy(k=>k.Employee.Id).Select(j=>j.GroupBy(‌​p=>p.GroupId)))
     .ToList();
```

this is the actual query i have,dont ask me how i wrote it..:P now i want to get id column from employeeLeaves and store it in some another variable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, which is why you've got so many answers with different approaches. If you're trying to turn the "collection of employees" into a "collection of IDs" then you want something like this:

```
var ids = emp.Select(x => x.Id);
```

Or more directly:

```
var ids = db.Employees.Select(x => x.Id);
```

(Optionally with `ToList` at the end of each of these.)

I would strongly advise you to learn LINQ (and the somewhat-related languages features such as `var`) thoroughly, from scratch, with the help of a good book or tutorial. Learning bits piecemeal by just finding samples which do something a bit like what you want is not a good approach, IMO.

Comment: what i have is like this  var emp= db.employees.where(x=>x.Name=="piyush").toList(); now this var emp hav a particular record in which empname(piyush) empid(5) and salary(20k) is there...so i want to access this empid and store it in some anothervariable

Comment: var employeeLeaves = db.Leaves.Include("Employee").Include("Employee.Manager").Where(l => l.Status.Id == 1).GroupBy(l => l.Employee.Manager.Id).Select(l=>l.GroupBy(k=>k.Employee.Id).Select(j=>j.GroupBy(p=>p.GroupId)))
                .ToList(); this is the actual query i have,dont ask me how i wrote it..:P now i want to get id column from employeeLeaves

Comment: @PiyushSardana: That's *not* your actual code, because C# is case-sensitive. It's also not what you had in your original question. It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve, or why you've got the code you have. Please edit the *question* to make all of this clear. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Thank you so much but i think i have found my answer var id=emp[0].empId; This is what i wanted to get...Thanks anyways i think i posted the question in a wrong way..

Comment: @PiyushSardana: Well if you only want the ID, you should probably change your query *before* the `ToList` call - and also using `FirstOrDefault`. Otherwise you'll be fetching a huge amount of data you're not using.

Answer (score 3):

```
var empId = db.Employees.Single(x => x.id == 5).Id;
```

Comment: no i dont want to fetch emp id directly from employees table, i have a few records from that table in var emp..how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
var empIds = db.Employees.Select(e=>e.EmpID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select`. Maybe something like this:

```
var result=db.Employees
              .Select(s=>s.emp_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Database.Tablename.Single(x => x.id == anyId)
```

This should select single row